# Instagram curl PHP 2023 post media url: /?__a=1&__d=dis

Tags: php

I trying to get the item on the next link (exemple):

```
https://www.instagram.com/p/D?__a=1&__d=dis
```

After some session i got the fallow message:

```
{"message":
    "Please wait a few minutes before you try again.",
    "require_login":true,
    "status":"fail"
}
```

I am using the curl to fix this problem but with no results, some ideias?

```
<?php

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

$arrSetHeaders = array(
  'origin: https://www.instagram.com',
  'authority: www.instagram.com',
  'upgrade-insecure-requests: 1',
  'Host: www.instagram.com',
  'accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3',
  'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br',
  'accept-language: en-GB,en;q=0.9',
  'cache-control: max-age=0',
  'sec-ch-ua: "Not_A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="109", "Chromium";v="109"',
  'sec-fetch-dest: document',
  'sec-fetch-mode: navigate',
  'sec-fetch-site: same-origin',
);

$ch = curl_init("https://www.instagram.com/p/D?__a=1&__d=dis");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__) . "/temp/cookies.txt" );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__) . "/temp/cookies.txt" );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $arrSetHeaders, "*");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "set-cookie: csrftoken=???; set-cookie: ds_user_id=???; set-cookie: sessionid=???");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);

echo '<pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">' . $data . '</pre>';
```

Comment: Sounds like the website doesn't want you automating access that way, and is forcing you to slow down your requests.

Comment: There any solution for that? Thanks

Comment: Use curl with various proxy servers options. Use different accounts with different CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE and CURLOPT_USERAGENT for each proxy server.